# Auto adjust component size in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have JFrame with different components like buttons and labels. I want my labels to auto adjust its height when screen resolution changes. I mostly work with NetBeans GUI components (*drag and drop*).

[image]

When the height resolution increases then every component height increases like this

[image]

Is there any way of doing so with some kind of layout etc or I have to manually get screen resolution and then repaint each component?

I am not a really manually coding for each component because mostly I just drag and drop in NetBeans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left side should be a JPanel that uses a GridLayout(0, 1) that then holds the 4 JLabels. The whole thing can be placed into a GridBagLayout-using JPanel or perhaps a BoxLayout.

> I am not a really manually coding for each component because mostly I just drag and drop in NetBeans.

and don't do this. If you want this functionality, read up on and use the layout managers rather than blindly dragging and dropping. You know that you can also create JPanels with NetBeans code generation tools and tell the JPanels what specific layouts to use.

Comment: how can you be that fast? I was writing a comment about the GridBagLayout when this appeared xD

Comment: I had some thoughts on using layouts but wasn't sure about this. Let me check and then accept your answer if this works.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels and knowledge about swing tough, I'm still trying to compete gurus like you, MadProgrammer, peeskillet, etc. While I'm still a newbie but I learn a lot from all of you C:

Comment: @AbdulJabbarWebBestow: Note that preferred sizes of JLabels can change based on the sizes of the text font or images that they display.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this doesn't change when the resolution changes

Comment: Though this wasn't the exact answer I was looking for but this gave me a start and that's all needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to detect changes to the screen resolution is to register an AWTEventListener.

When fired, you can check the resolution against the last known value and adjust your frame size accordingly.  This is where your choice of LayoutManager comes into play.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ResolutionChangedDemo implements Runnable
{
  private Dimension lastScreenSize;
  private JFrame frame;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ResolutionChangedDemo());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    lastScreenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    AWTEventListener listener = new AWTEventListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event)
      {
        Dimension actualScreenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        if (! lastScreenSize.equals(actualScreenSize))
        {
          System.out.println("resolution changed");
          lastScreenSize = actualScreenSize;

          // Here is where you would resize your frame appropriately
          // and the LayoutManager would do the rest
        }
      }
    };

    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.PAINT_EVENT_MASK);

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```